# NextJS 13.4, useRouter() is not working | pathname is undefined

Tags: next.js, path, router, next-router

I am trying to make an active link and change the styling to underline when it's active. I am using `useRouter()` from 'next/navigation', because importing **useRouter** from 'next/router' gives an error. But my link is still not working.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import hamburgerMenu from '../../public/Assets/hamburger-menu.svg';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';

function HamburgerMenu({ isModalOpen, handleModal }) {
    const { pathname } = useRouter();

    return (
        <>
            {isModalOpen && <></>}
            <button onClick={handleModal}>
                <Image src={hamburgerMenu} width={20} height={14} />
            </button>
            {isModalOpen && (
                <div className='absolute top-16 left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%]'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link href='/' className={pathname == '/' ? 'underline' : ''}>
                                Home
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link
                                href='/about'
                                className={pathname == '/about' ? 'underline' : ''}>
                                About
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default HamburgerMenu;
```

This code is working for everyone except me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `usePathname` hook

As of Nextjs 13 most of the api has changes include the router APIs.

Now to get the `pathName`, you need to use the `usePathname` from `'next/navigation'` as shown in the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname):

> `usePathname` is a Client Component hook that lets you read the
> current URL's pathname.
>
> ```
> 'use client'      
>
> import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation' 
>  
> export default function ExampleClientComponent() {      
>   const pathname = usePathname()      
>   return <>Current pathname: {pathname}</>
> }
> ```

### Aside

That goes also for accessing search params, 2 new API [useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) and [useParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params).